# How do I open a minecraft server console that has been started in the background by a shell script?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, raspberrypi, minecraft

So I'm running a Minecraft server off of a raspberry pi 4B. If I use a script to automatically start the server in the background, then there isn't a way I know of to access the server console. I can use the `screen` command to start it then have it run in the background, but to detach from a screen you have to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>,<kbd>d</kbd> which I can't do in a script to my knowledge so I can't automate it this way. Are there any solutions that would allow me to start the server on boot and access the server console when I need to?

Comment: To me using `screen` sounds like a good idea. I didn't try it but you may be able to use `screen -d` to detach screen from a script.

Comment: Do you want to know how to start Minecraft Server headless using `screen`? (Yes, it's possible). Or do you want to access some particular command in the console that you cannot already access from your Client? Please remember that is is a Question/Answer site, not a forum. Try to ask a single answerable question.

Comment: Check the `fg` command.

Answer (score 0):

I  used advice from this post: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/454098/548051
to forward console to tty:

```
User=minecraft
WorkingDirectory=/home/minecraft/minecraft/
ExecStart=/home/minecraft/minecraft/bedrock_server
RestartSec=10
StartLimitBurst=100
StandardInput=tty-force
TTYVHangup=yes
TTYPath=/dev/tty20
TTYReset=yes
Type=simple
```

and access it from conspy:

```
sudo conspy 20
```

Answer (score 0):

you could just enable the RCon (remote console) in the server.properties file and access it with for example [mcrcon](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mcrcon/)

Comment: with it you would not even need to be on the pi to access it,  just know the ip, port and password.